# Accessing ParentForm from UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

The program I am writing includes a console. I've created a `UserControl` called Console. This Console class has multiple background workers doing various tasks. The problem I have run into is that if I place this control on a form and then close it, I occasionally run into problems where the `BackgroundWorker` threads are making calls to disposed objects.

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event), I need to stop the form closing and handle the close request myself. I have most of this written successfully, but the major problem I'm running into is subscribing to the `ParentForm`'s `FormClosing` event.

I've been trying to use `this.ParentForm` but I can't find a good place where this isn't null.

Of course, I can't do this in the constructor, as it is being generated at this point.

I also can't use this in the `ParentChanged` event as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784551/how-parentform-reference-is-null). When this fires, `this.Parent` is no longer null, but that's not `this.ParentForm`. I realize sometimes it could be, but for example, I currently have this sitting in a tab control so that's not quite what I want.

Then we also have [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871578/parentform-is-null-in-a-button-inside-a-usercontrol-inside-a-form) to try hooking into the `this.Load` function (I'm referencing the second answer, not the selected one) but again, `this.ParentForm` is null here. As before, `this.Parent` has a value but it's not quite what I want.

Finally, I thought I found the solution to my problem when I came across [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d0d10b90-2e65-4813-8d1c-cd054f4c69c7/usercontrol-close-exit-terminate-etc) suggesting to override `OnCreateControl` but yet again... no luck, both are null.

After the form is loaded, I have added a button that I can press, and at that point, I have been able to determine that `this.ParentForm` does in fact get populated correctly.

My question- where can I get the `UserControl`'s `this.ParentForm` where it isn't null so I can subscribe to it's events?

Edit: Adding some of my code per LarsTech's request:

The result of this code is:

> This.Parent has a value
>
> This.ParentForm is null

```
private MyConsole(string COMPort)
{
    // I do this so that the console window is created by the time I have started my Background Workers
    this.CreateHandle();

    // Generate the form
    InitializeComponent();
        
    // set the COM Port Name
    _COMPort = COMPort;
    ReadOnly = true;
    ActiveCloseRequest = false;

    // This just creates 1 or 2 background workers
    StartBackgroundWorkers();

    this.ParentChanged += MyConsole_ParentChanged;            
}
void MyConsole_ParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Parent == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This.Parent is null");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This.Parent has a value");
    }
    if (this.ParentForm == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This.ParentForm is null");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This.ParentForm has a value");
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this tagged asp and wpf? Is this silverlight or can you specify which UI framework you are using because it sounds a lot more like winforms.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, you're quite right. I've changed it.

Comment: Make your control inherit `ISupportInitialize` which will make the designer use `BeginInit` and `EndInit` calls when creating your control. You can then get the parent form using `this.FindForm()` in the `EndInit` method.

Comment: I'm already inheriting from `UserControl`, so I can't also inherit from `ISupportInitialize` can I?

Comment: Yes, its an interface, not a concrete class, you can inherit from multiple interfaces but only one concrete class, it would look like `public MyControl : UserControl, ISupportInitialize { ... }`

Comment: Ah, I should have known that. I was thrown off by you saying inherit, I didn't realize that also applied when using interfaces. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I see where several other `UserControl`'s I've created call `BeginInit()` and `EndInit` but for some reason this one does not. I didn't manually delete them though I may have done something else that would have gotten rid of it. Any idea?

Comment: Make sure to delete the control, rebuild your project, and then add it to the form again, it won't work if you just change it without re-adding it.

Comment: Can we move to chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87914/discussion-between-bkribbs-and-ron-beyer

Comment: I apologize, I can't, I'm working.

Comment: It's not clear to me why the ParentForm property can't be used in the ParentChanged event.  I'm pretty sure that works.

Comment: I just verified that `this.Parent` is not `null` but `this.ParentForm` is. Not sure why that's the case.

Comment: You would have to show us that code that does that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I verified in the `ParentChanged` event that `this.Parent` is not `null` but `this.ParentForm` is. My code for that is just checking if they are null or not and printing a line to indicate either way.

Comment: Again, you would have to show us the code that does that.

Comment: Done. Could creating the handle myself have anything to do with it?

Comment: I can't recreate your issue, but I wouldn't manually create the handle.  I would probably prefer to start your background workers in that ParentChanged event, making sure 1) the ParentForm isn't null, and 2) the workers haven't been started yet.

Comment: I commented out the creating of the handle, as well as the starting of the workers. Nothing changed, I still got This.Parent having a value and This.ParentForm being null.

Comment: Having your Parent have a value but ParentForm be null is odd.  I get values for both Parent and ParentForm.  How are you creating this control?  Obviously you aren't using the designer since it has a parameter in the constructor.

Comment: I believe it was created through the designer, I just added a parameter to the constructor. I added a new UserControl, called it MyConsole, stuck a RichTextBox on that control, then just went into the MyConsole class and did lots of editing there.

Comment: I meant, you aren't placing this UserControl on a Form using the designer — it would throw an exception without a parameterless constructor.  So how is this UserControl getting placed on a form?  Use the `@` sign in StackOverflow to signal a user in comments.

Comment: @LarsTech I thought you get a notification when you're the last comment. Sorry about that! Right- first I do `MyConsole console = new MyConsole("COM7")` then I have another form which has a tab control on it. I then generate a new tabpage and do `TabPage.Controls.Add(console);` and then I add that tabpage to the tabcontrol. Make sense?

Comment: Well, the bottom line is, the code you posted doesn't reproduce the problem.  Try recreating the problem in a new project, and if it happens, post that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing the cleanup inside the `Dispose()` method of the UserControl instead? It is usually a more logical place to do this, as a form closing will then dispose its children controls.

Unfortunately, the auto-generated user control template puts the `Dispose()` method in the associated `.Designer.cs` file. But you can move the method to your main file instead and modify it to perform the cleanup.

Comment: This is the method I ended up using, I moved the Dispose to my file and handled it from there.